# Have firefox ask me where to save downloads

Tags: mac, firefox, download

I am using Firefox 3.6.8 on a Mac with OS 10.6.4.  How do I make it so that every time I download a file, firefox will ask me what location I want to save the file in?

Answer (score 1):

Tools > Options > General

Set the radio button to ask you where to save files.

Comment: I was actually asking because I just got a mac, but I figured it out.  Thanks!

Comment: @silenttothbone If you have solved your problem, please mark the appropriate answer as accepted, or if none of the answers were your solution, please post a new answer yourself with the solution you found and mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Firefox > Preferences... > General Tab > Under "Downloads" Select "Ask me where to save files"